# how to use $state.go with a sub state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to switch states into a substate from its parent page. Here is my setup:

1. I've a form (url: /session) that has ng-click attached
2. the ng-click runs a $resource POST, and calls
3. $state.go on success in order to navigate to the new page (url: /session/:sessionId)

I have separate controllers for the two states.

```
.config( function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider
  .state( 'alkalom', {
    url: '/alkalmak',
    controller: 'AlkalomCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html',
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Alkalmak' }
  })
  .state('alkalom.details', {
    url: '/:alkalomId',
    controller: 'AlkalomItemCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'home/alkalom.tpl.html',
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Alkalom' }
  });
})
.controller( 'AlkalomCtrl', function HomeController( $scope, Global, Alkalom , $stateParams, $state) {
  console.log('AlkalomCtrl initialized', $stateParams);
  $scope.alkalmak = Alkalom;
  $scope.setupAlkalom = function(alkalom) {
    alkalom = new Alkalom(alkalom);
    alkalom.$save(function(value, hdrs){
      $state.go('.details', {'alkalomId': value._id});
    });
  };
  $scope.today = function() {
    return Date.now().day;
  };
  $scope.nextHour = function() {
    return Date.now().hour + 1;
  }
})
.controller('AlkalomItemCtrl', function AlkalomItemCtrl($scope, Global, Alkalom, $stateParams) {
      console.log('AlkalomItemCtrl initialized', $stateParams);
      $scope.jogasok = Global.getJogasok();
      $scope.alkalom = Alkalom.get($stateParams.alkalomId)
      $scope.addJogas = function(jogas) {
        $scope.jogasok = Global.addJogas( jogas );
        $scope.addResztvevo(jogas);
      };
      $scope.addResztvevo = function(jogas) {
        $scope.alkalom.$addResztvevo({
          '_id': $scope.alkalom._id,
          'jogas': jogas._id
        }, function(value, hdrs) {
          $scope.alkalom = value;
          // .resztvevok.push(jogas);
        });
      };
      $scope.removeResztvevo = function(index) {
        $scope.alkalom.resztvevok.splice(index, 1)
        $scope.alkalom.$save();
      };
    });
```

You can see the log statements here. At step 1, the first log runs. But no more logs are run at all! Still the location hash changes in the browser.

Should $state.go used differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used  tags in the main states' view.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/G450hacLevbsswFK0vKK?p=preview